# set transparent layer on the 3d model and draw something on the transparent layer and project on the surface

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, mapping, projection

I have done lots of research on projection mapping but did not found any solution that i want to do like map on the real 3d object by projector through iPad or desktop.
I want to draw something on the real time 3d object from ipad application. I have 3d model of that object and connect the iPad from projector, In the real time if i will Draw line on the 3d model it will display as it is on the 3d object by projector. It should be look like i am drawing on the real object.

I want to do something like...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RoeDacxjtA4

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its obviously need extensive research but i have an idea in my mind.

1. Match real model and a 3d model in unity.
2. Your virtual camera need to be positioned exactly same way your real life projector is positioned. Your FOV need to be same as your projector
3. Virtual camera is to see only overlay layer, not the 3d object itself. So will give you only picture with the paint you can directly project on the real object

Regarding painting on the 3d model, there will be numbers of ways you can make it. There probably are some useful assets in the asset store you can buy

That looks interesting
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/digital-paint-free-mesh-painting-in-unity-download.95535/

Comment: Thanks Gerg that is good idea. I think it is perfect i can achieve this goal by this idea.Is there any idea how the virtual camera will project the overlay layer on the 3d object.Is there any script for that.

Comment: Virtual camera is not projecting anything, it just looks at the painted overlay and passing it to the projector.

Comment: If you happy with my answer please accept it by clicking on the tick on left side, thanks

Comment: how can we pass virtual camera rendering to projector in unity ?

Comment: You simply make a standalone build to PC or MAC, run it and plug projector to the computer? I thought thats obvious?